Ubuntu 24.04 (Wayland): swap (remap) Escape and Backtick (tilde)
I've been using the X11 setup, but recently switched to 24.04 with the Wayland server.
How do I swap the keys (in the upper left) for Escape and Backtick (`) (which is Tilde if shifted?  Here's what I used to do in my .xmodmap
keycode 49 = Escape
keycode 9 = grave asciitilde

Thanks, there seems to be many complicated approaches, so I'm looking for the simplest, well supported solution.

This question is similar to: Remap keys with modifiers on Ubuntu 18.04 Wayland. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

thanks moo. that one's 5 years old and there are many more options for this now.

I should add that most people who just want to swap caps-lock and control can use gnome-tweaks with Xwayland and Ubuntu 24.04+: apt install gnome-tweaks

There seem to be several software packages that claim to support this, but the one that worked for me was "Input Remapper".
I had to essentially run:
sudo apt install input-remapper
input-remapper-gtk  # interactive
sudo systemctl start input-remapper

The UI is a bit confusing, but once I found the right "key names" I was able to get it working. e.g. "grave" not "backtick" not "`". This also works at the console as well as in X11. It should work in Xorg servers too, but I didn't test that.
